# Axios Delete 405 (Method Not Allowed) Error with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am using ReactJS as client side web app and I'm using axios package. In my backend, I am using Django Rest Framework. I created Serializer for CartItem Model:

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        # Fields you want to be returned or posted
        fields = '__all__'
```

Viewset:

```
class CartItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CartItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartItemSerializer
```

I am trying to use default delete method of DRF in axios using so:

```
axios.delete('cart_items/', {
                headers: { Authorization: 'Token token' },
                data: {
                    id: 1,
                },
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
```

When I call that, it gives me error in React: DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart_items/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your URL. The URL should point toward the ***`CartItem` instance*** (the URL of ***`DetailView`***)
So, The URL should be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart_items/123/
```

Where, the **`123`** is the **`PK`** of the instance to be deleted. Also you don't have to attach the `payload` to the request since it has no effect on DRF side.

---

```
axios.delete('cart_items/1/', {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Token token' },

})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
axios.delete('cart_items/',
```

You have to provide the url of rest endpoint like 'localhost:port/cart_items/'
if the server is running locally on some port